# Swift Issue with adding value to array for use within UITableView Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, compiler-errors, picker

Confused as to why getting error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [[String]]' (aka 'inout Array>'). Within a working table view class

(Originally followed Jared Davidson tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR6dR-vVZeY)

```
var secondArray = [SecondTable]()

let latest = ViewController().getArrayListLast()
var latestClass = latest.getFullClasses()

print(latestClass[0])

for i in 0...(latest.getAssetClasses().count)
{
    if SecondTable(secondTitle: latestClass[i]) != nil
    {
       secondArray = secondArray.append(SecondTable(secondTitle: latestClass[i]))
    }
}
```

Comment: The default initializer `ViewController()` will never work when using storyboard.

Comment: at first: it can be an outdatet Tutorial, because swift 3 is started in sep 2017 - better choose a other tutorial

Comment: please add the code of the (for me unknown - and no i don't watch the 40min video) functions:  `.getArrayListLast()` `.getFullClasses()` `.getAssetClasses()` and the class of `SecondTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538872-append) is mutating function and it doesn't return anything.

Now your code making 3 more mistakes.

1. As @vadian mentioned in comment `ViewController()` will never work when using storyboard.
2. It will give you run time crash index out of bounds because you have provide for loop till the array count but it should be till the less one of the array count, so it should like `for i in 0..<(latest.getAssetClasses().count)`
3. You are creating two times object with init of `SecondTable` to just check for the nil instead of that you can use `if let`.

   ```
   if let secondTable = SecondTable(secondTitle: latestClass[i]) {
      secondArray.append(secondTable)
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey, 1. Does work as I have another main class called ViewController and has worked so far

Comment: what should I use instead of append then

Comment: @MatthewClisby Check my edited answer it is simply `secondArray.append(secondTable)`